# BLE ReadValue for particular characteristic throws "Resource Insufficient Error"

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

I'm trying to read a particular characteristic. And it is failing to read the value of characteristics. If I try to connect it using nRFConnect, it is properly reading the value.

Comment: What's the full error message? Did you read `error.localization` or `error`? Also, could you check the properties of the characteristic? Could it be encrypted (`indicateEncryptionRequired` for instance), and you need to pair with it before being able to read it.

Comment: Yes after pairing only I tried to read it. And I read error.localizedDescription. Will check about the encrypted thing.

Comment: We are clear that pairing, is done when an iOS pop-up is show telling explicitly that, and that's not a simple "didConnect", right?

Comment: I'm getting this error. "Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=17 "Resources are insufficient." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Resources are insufficient.}​

"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes found the answer. **The issue was with the BLE Device**. Even in nRFConnect the same error was printed in the log. This happened when we discover descriptors for a particular characteristic. Hopefully the log from nRFConnect saved me :)

When I tried to switch off and switch on the BLE Device or Remove the battery and re-insert it again the problem was solved. :)